# TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): constraints

Tags: python, django

I have a project in django and when I try to do the migrations it sends me the following error:

```
File "C:\andon\f2candon\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 195, in 
contribute_to_class
    raise TypeError("'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): %s" % ','.join(meta_attrs))
TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): constraints
```

The code segment where the error sends me is the following, in the file options.py:

```
# Any leftover attributes must be invalid.
        if meta_attrs != {}:
            raise TypeError("'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): %s" % ','.join(meta_attrs))
```

Comment: What Django version are you using? Django's constraint framework was introduced in 2.2.

Comment: 2.1.15, I've just installed 2.2.9 version but i got this error: `" File "C:\andon\f2candon\venv\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Django %d.%d.%d is not supported." % VERSION[:3])
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 2.2.9 is not supported. "`

Comment: it looks like you are using a package `sql_server` that either does not support 2.2.9, or should be upgraded as well.

Comment: I am using the "django-pyodbc-azure" package, and this one needs django 2.1.15, is there any way that I don't get the error?

Comment: but `constraints =...` was added to `Meta` in Django-2.2, so that means you should remove this from the `Meta`, or somehow upgrade your project.

Answer (score 2):

try changing rest_framework version in your virtual environment or docker to 3.9.1

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it seems clear enough. Try to expand it more if you wish, including how and why in order to help more users in the future.